# How can I filter Submitted list by multiple user in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

How can I filter the "Submitted" view by multiple users in perforce?
I want to just see only a few(4-5?) people in the "Submitted" view.
There is a filter function, but filter doesn't take multiple users.
So, can I specify multiple users in the "Submitted" view at perforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this in either p4v (the GUI) or p4 (CLI). Your best bet is to pass this as a feature request to the excellent perforce support.

Comment: Still not possible in P4V 2014.3/1007540

Answer (score 1):

I have created a power shell script that could be helpful.
It filters for a specific user, date and you can chose the last number of entries you want to search within (this accelerates the command return).
The result is shown in a power shell grid window which helps you to sort the result entries.
Please feel free to modify variables for your requirements:

```
$date1 = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y/%m/%d"  #today
#$date1 = "2013/09/11"   #other day
$users = "user1|user2|user3"
$title = "Submitted changes on: "+$date1+" and users: "+$users
$maxLines = 100

Write-host -foregroundcolor 'cyan' $title

$out = (p4 changes -t -s submitted -m 512 | select-string -Pattern $users | select-string -Pattern $date1)

$out | Select-Object LineNumber,Line,Matches | Out-GridView -Title $title -PassThru
```

Ihsan

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Just my two cents:

I wanted to filter the submitted list to avoid changelists from other projects on the same P4 server. I tried to filter by user at first, but no luck, just like you.

*But!* I finally achieved what I wanted by **filtering by file** path. That way, only my project is visible. I find this quite usefull, as it will show any activity from someone I didn't expect on my project. It's event better than filtering by name. In ma specific case at least.

It doesn't answer the question directly, but it fix the problem I did face :)

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to another filter such as grep. For example,

```
p4 changes -s submitted | egrep "^[^@]* (tom|dick|harry)@"
```

You may need to modify the regular expression to suit your output format. The <kbd>^[^@]*</kbd> prevents false positives such as  <kbd>tom@</kbd> in the summary.